# Synchronizing two UIScrollBar's

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4

I have a page from my application which have 2 UIScrollBars objects I will name it scrol1 and scrol2, scrol1 is on the left of scrol2 I want to achieve this;

When the scrol2 scrolls from right to left and (left to right) the scrol1 not to scroll, when scrol2 scrolls from top to bottom and(bottom to top) the scrol1 to scroll with scrol2 in synchrone. How I can do this trick. Please provide some examples or ideas.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

During the creation of your scroll views you should create a Key Value Observer (KVO) for the contentOffset of your scroll view scrol2

```
NSKeyValueObservingOptions options = NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld;
[scrol2 addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentOffset" options:options context:nil];
```

Then in the method to observe the value, scroll your scrollviews according to your wished scroll behaviour.

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    CGPoint new = [[change objectForKey:@"new"] CGPointValue];
    CGPoint old = [[change objectForKey:@"old"] CGPointValue];
    // it could be necessary to convert your scroll offset for the other scroll view
    [scrol1 setContentOffset:new];
}
```